# Are tennis shoes good to use for jogging and on a treadmill?

Tags: running-shoes, jogging, shoes, treadmill

Are tennis shoes good to use for jogging and on a treadmill? Or any other type sports shoes?

Comment: If you go to the Reebok store, they have there different types of shoes for different tasks.

Comment: @Anisha - OK. will check nearest rebook store. but I think it would be bit costly.

Comment: Yes they are a bit costly at the same time they are too comfortable too, you should purchase them in the SALE. Reebok always has the FLAT 40% off during SALE.

Comment: Yes and it's also confusing the shoes they have lots of options and categories See this page http://www.reebok.com/IN/womens/footwear and go to Sports/Activity they have different shoes for Running, Walking and Fitness & Training. I can't afford 3 different shoes.

Comment: Walking and running definitely need different shoes. They are different activities. For Gym, you don't need any particular shoes, I think. Secondly why are you looking for women's shoes? Are you a girl? You name doesn't suggest so.

Comment: I want to buy shoes for my wife actually

Comment: @AnishaKaul let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/723/discussion-between-jitendra-vyas-and-anisha-kaul)

Answer (score 4):

No - tennis shoes are going to be slightly heavier and have more material/cushioning around the sides.  They are meant for stability and lots of side to side movement.  Running shoes are lighter and are built for forward movement.  You will experience aches of all kinds of you do jogging/running in tennis shoes at any amount of frequency more than about a mile a day.